# Get table name from accdb in Node Js

Tags: javascript, node.js, ms-access

I need to list the table name from a DB in MS Access in Node JS. I try using

```
var ADODB = require('node-adodb');
ADODB.debug = true;

// Connect to the MS Access DB
var connection = ADODB.open('Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;DataSource=C:\\Users\\Omar\\Documents\\1.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;');

router.get('/',function (peticion,respuesta){
console.log("estamos en el get");

connection
    .query('SELECT [NAME] from MSysObjects WHERE Type In (1,4,6) and Left ([Name],4) <> "MSys"')

    .on('done', function (data){
        //console.log('Result:'.green, data);

        for (var x = 0; x < data.records.length;x ++){
          console.log(data.records[x]);
        }
        console.log(data.records);
        respuesta.render('index.jade', {peliculas: data.records});
    });

});
```

But give me the error "Operation is not allowed if the object is closed" and I can't fix it.

Thanks and sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue ^^
If you are using the last version of node-adodb, you just have to comments theses lines to display the real error message:

```
node-adodb/lib/adodb.js:496 -> //recordset.Close();
node-adodb/lib/adodb.js:497 -> //connection.Close();
```

Mine was a server version problem !

If you need more information, you can see the issue here:
https://github.com/nuintun/node-adodb/issues/9

Hope it helps :)